# I am not allowed to view Ubuntu Forums. Restricted from viewing any page on http://ubuntuforums.org

Tags: restricted

My account is the same email for this and I don't think I did anything against the rules. Please help me figure out the reason for being restricted.

Thanks,
Matt S.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Forums and Ask Ubuntu aren't directly related. **We cannot help you directly.**

But if you are currently banned (or blocked, or whatever), I would strongly suggest talking to the [forums' community council](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ForumCouncil). This is the official body that is responsible for the conduct on the Forums. They should be able to let you know the situation.

They provide out-of-band contact information too, so you don't have to post on UF to get help.